# core bluetooth crash in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, core-bluetooth

I have developed a bluetooth app, which runs fine on iOS 6, but when I run it on iOS 7 the application crashes in the -didDiscoverPeripheral call back. The crash info suggests that a release is called on the CBPeripheral object. I have used ARC for memory management, here is my declaration,initialisation  of the CBPeripheral object and the call back code:

```
@interface BrLEDiscovery () <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate> {
    CBCentralManager    *centralManager;
    CBPeripheral *currentperipheral;
    BOOL                pendingInit;
}


- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        pendingInit = YES;
        centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
       currentperipheral=[[CBPeripheral alloc]init];
        founddevice=FALSE;
        foundPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        connectedServices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{ NSLog(@"Found Peripheral %@",[peripheral name]);

    if ([[peripheral name] isEqualToString:peripheralname]) {
        founddevice=TRUE;
        currentperipheral=peripheral;

        if (![foundPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {
            [foundPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
            [discoveryDelegate discoveryDidRefresh];
            [discoveryDelegate DiscoveryDidFindDevice:peripheral];

        }

        [RecursiveScanTimer invalidate];
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post it. The code itself looks more or less Ok considering flow control and syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it's pretty likely to be crashing on this line:

```
currentperipheral=peripheral;
```

To me, it's kinda messy allocating a `CBPeripheral` object in your init and then assigning the peripheral at an unknown time later (especially with arc). If you want to keep reference to a discovered peripheral, just create a `CBPeripheral` object in your interface, retain the discovered peripheral, and assign it to your interface peripheral.

Just try something like this:

```
currentPeripheral = [discoveredPeripheral retain];//where discoveredPeripheral is the one given in the delegate callback
```

I personally don't use arc for any of my corebluetooth related applications..You need to be really careful with the corebluetooth framework and peripheral references though...it gets messyyy.

Note: If you do not always need to have direct contact with the peripheral, it's often handy to just keep a record of the `CFUUIDRef` (or `identifier` for iOS 7) and just retrieve the peripheral whenever you need it... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot,declaring it in the interface and not allocating it in init seems to work. I still don't understand why the instance variable initialized in init is being deallocated when I try to reassign it in the callback. And the fact that this is only happening on iOS7 adds even more to my confusion. Is there something fundamental that I am missing in ARC??

Comment: Nice catch! @Yash never allocate a `CBPeripheral` object. Use `nil` instead in the initialization. The reason for the crash happening in iOS7 is probably some internal change in the CBPeripheral class' dealloc method. Without the crash report this is hard to tell.

Comment: allprog. Yep, I just removed my alloc init from the blePeripheral declarations on load and hey presto, no more crash on VC dealloc